# Android Nexus soft keyboard covers edittext field slightly

Tags: android

[image]
[image]

Hello, I faced up Android UI-issue today.

Please, look at the red box in the above image.

First, screenshot was captured on Nexus phone.
Second, screenshot was captured on other phone. (Samsung, LG, etc..)

These 2 pictures are using same code.

but only nexus keyboard hides edit text a little more than other phone.
So, edit text is a little bit more hidden, meaning UI looks a bit ugly.

how to solve this issue?

Comment: android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen" in your edittext

Comment: Sad to say but the only solution for this is some sort of designing the layout based on the manufacturer. You need to do this on code because XML doesn't provide this fallbacks.

Comment: also if you are using a scrollview then use android:isScrollContainer="true". in scrollview

Comment: did you tired with Chinese keyboard on samsung phone? Does the problem occurs?

Comment: @leesc I am facing almost same problem. Have you found any solution?